# How to remove those minor parts using opencv?

Tags: opencv

Each image is expected to contain only one corn kernel. Unfortunately, a corn may overlap with its neighbors. So I hope to keep the largest one and remove those minor parts.

[image: sample 1: expected] [image: sample 2: unexpected] [image: sample 3: unexpected]

From left to right, the first image is the expected case, and remaining two are unexpected case. Using cv2, can somebody help me change the two unexpected cases to an expected case?

Comment: You can try morphological operations after converting the image to a binary one

Comment: @JeruLuke Nice idea. As you suggested, I just tried erosion with a large kernel. Althogh it doesn't solve the problem entirely, this trick does make it better now.